# Applying pandas groupby over two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes. They are identical in shape and form. They each contain a number of simulations, and each simulation streches over an identical number of steps, denoted `time`.

```
df_init = pd.DataFrame({'sim' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                        'time' : [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
                        'values' : [1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3]
                        })

df_next = pd.DataFrame({'sim' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                        'time' : [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
                        'values' : [2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 7]
                        })

df_init
Out[3]: 
    sim  time  values
0     1     0       1
1     1     1       2
2     1     2       1
3     1     3       0
4     2     0       2
5     2     1       1
6     2     2       2
7     2     3       3

df_next
Out[4]: 
    sim  time  values
0     1     0       2
1     1     1       4
2     1     2       5
3     1     3       6
4     2     0       3
5     2     1       4
6     2     2       5
7     2     3       7
```

I want construct a new dataframe where for each simulation `sim` the first `n` timesteps are from `df_init` and the rest is from `df_next`.

If for instance `n=2` the result would look like this

```
df_result
Out[3]: 
    sim  time  values
0     1     0       1
1     1     1       2
2     1     2       5
3     1     3       6
4     2     0       2
5     2     1       1
6     2     2       5
7     2     3       7
```

If there was only one simulation this would be easy

```
df_next.iloc[:n] = df_init.iloc[:n]
```

But how can I do this when there is a bunch of simulations? I thought about `groupby()` but I really don't know how to apply it to combine two dataframes.

This is, of course, a constructed example. In my real data I have a bunch of value-columns, thousands of simulations and the time variable streches several hundred steps.

And again, I am guaranteed that the dataframes have the same shape, and the columns `sim` and `time` will be identical in both dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need filter by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) - starts from `0`, so subtract `1`, then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) togetehr and sort by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
n=2
a = df_init[df_init.groupby('sim').cumcount() <= n-1]
b = df_next[df_next.groupby('sim').cumcount() >  n-1]

df = pd.concat([a,b]).sort_values('sim')
print (df)
   sim  time  values
0    1     0       1
1    1     1       2
2    1     2       5
3    1     3       6
4    2     0       2
5    2     1       1
6    2     2       5
7    2     3       7
```

Comment: jezrael to the rescue! It sure looks like that worked. I needed to adjust `sort_values(['sim', 'time'])`... but that was trivial. Thanks!